# Exploratory, session-based testing testing with testlink

Tags: testing, bdd, performance-testing, testlink, exploratory

I'm using Testlink, and I want to make it a hub for the management of as many types of tests as possible, but I'm struggling with how to properly take advantage of Testlink in:
- Exploratory and session-based tests
- Performance, Stress and Volume tests
- BDD

Is there a way to use Testlink for the management of these type of tests, and behavior-driven development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Different suite of test scripts can be managed in TestLink including Non Functional. However, will have to follow a proper nomenclature for the same. The master - child folder structure will cater to your requirements.

Note: Different Projects can be created from Test Project Management module to manage the tests.

Make Master folder with Project name
Child Level 1 Folder Release name
Child Level 2 Folder Test Suite name 
Child Level 3 Actual Test Scripts with test steps